# java inputHandler error

Tags: java

I can't get what is going wrong in the following program. When i compile it give some error. in the line which i have bold.

`import java.util.*;
public class Kutty
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    byte a[]={5,2,3};
    char c;
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    c=scan.nextChar();
    for(byte x :a)
    {
        System.out.println("hello"+x);`

}

}

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want getting char input there are more ways to do it . One of them :

- Read as a string and cast to char

  ```
   Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
   String s = scan.next();

   char c =  Character.valueOf(s.charAt(0));
  ```

Answer (score 3):

`Scanner` does not have a method called `nextChar()`. That's the error.

With Scanner you'll read a complete line, usually to a `String` object. The `nextXXX` method are convenience methods to convert *tokens* (= white-space separated parts of the input) to another format. Like you enter an number (+ CR/LF), call `nextInt()` and the scanner class trys to convert the next token to a number.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is already answered, I just want to recommend getting an IDE that will help you identify these type of problems.

These are the most widely used ones:

1. [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)
2. [IntelliJIDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/)